# Batch programing to rename files

Tags: batch-file, renaming

I would like to rename files using batch script.

The files are currently named like this:

```
pkg_mon_doc_kpps_01.html
pkg_mon_doc_kpps_10.html
pkg_mon_doc_kpps_02.html
```

And I'd like to change them to:

```
data_1.xls
data_2.xls
data_3.xls
```

I made batch file, and when  I ran the script, renaming successfully but with a warning

**My batch script :**

```
@echo off
set count=0
:: Getting number of files
for %%x in (folder\*.html) do (set /a count+=1)

:: Renaming files
for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (ren folder\*.html data_%%a.xls)
pause
```

**Warning**

```
A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.
A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.
A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

what's wrong? thanks before :)

Comment: You get those warnings because for every %%a in %count% it tries to rename **all** the .html files in folder to data_%%a.xls. So, when a=1, it renames the first html file to data_1.xls and then shows **2 warnings** when renaming the next two files to data_1.xls. At the next step, there are only two .html files left so it renames the first one data_2.xls and shows **1 warning** for the next. At the last step, there is only one .html file left so it renames it data_3.xls without warnings. In total, for the example you provided, you should get **3 warnings**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you ask to rename all files in folder at once (`ren folder\*.html data_%%a.xls`)

so all *.html are rename to data_1.xls.

you need a loop to rename files one by one.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
:: Renaming files
for %%a in (folder\*.html) do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "fname=%%~a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    ren "!fname!" data_!count!.xls
    endlocal
)
```

and a solution without `delayed expansion`:

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d folder\*.html^|findstr /n $') do ren "folder\%%~b" data_%%a.xls
```

Comment: +1, whoops, I didn't notice your 2nd solution which is nearly identical to what I had later posted. I deleted my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You must combine your loops:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "count=0"
for %%x in (folder\*.html) do (
    set /a "count+=1"
    call ren "%%x" "data_%%count%%.xls"
)
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: this doesn't work with file names containing exclamation marks.

Comment: Now it does, thx for reminding me. I'm usually an DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION apologet.

Comment: good point, i rarely see filenames with those. But that is certainly an issue worth solving.